latest update for flutter 3.22.2 for ios is broken
While debugging everything works fine, but when uploaded to appstore or testflight, after some time the app is breaks, blinking and not responding, the reason of such behaviour is not found, it may appear at first start or after some time of use.
(00000004:kIOGPUCommandBufferCallbackErrorSubmissionsIgnored)
2024-07-22 16:10:51.581818+0600 Runner[9730:2054346] Execution of 
the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. 
Ignored (for causing prior/excessive GPU errors)

Does anybody faced the same issues?


Rolled back to flutter version 3.19.6, seems to work fine. The issue might be from flutter itself or from packages maybe, will wait a next upgrade, maybe that will work

I ran into the same problem on flutter 3.24.5 using xcode 16.1 (16B40). The problem was solved by switching to flutter beta 3.27.0-0.2.pre.
Additional information can be found here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/153574
